# REMI Repository RPMs validated or tested?

Tags: php, mysql, updates, yum

We are currently looking at starting more consistent updates on our servers and want to be running the most current packages that are considered stable as possible.  We run mainly Centos 6 servers with a few Centos 5 servers that need to be rebuilt/replaced in the near future.  One of the servers in particular we are looking to update needs MySQL 5.5 and PHP 5.5 for the application running on it.  It currently has the base yum repo on a Centos 6 machine and we are looking at using remi and epel as additional repos for more current packages.

When evaluating the processes and procedures we want to start using for these updates, we are looking at doing REMI Repository installations or getting the source code or RPMs from the vendors to do the updates.  A couple of the questions that were asked by our superiors were:

1. Are the RPMs signed?
2. Is any testing or validity of the installations packages done prior to the release?

We were able to answer the first one from the [remi website documentation](http://www.google.com/url?q=http://blog.famillecollet.com/pages/Config-en&sa=D&sntz=1&usg=AFQjCNEG-RNaEijmNzP54otbUr43mRtaiw) with a yes.

We are mainly in need of documentation answering the second question posed to us.  We have searched for a while now and have not found anything answering this question to date, and from a search of the stackoverflow posts I have not seen anything along these lines either.

Any assistance in finding documentation with an answer would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Software Collections repository (maintained by Red Hat) is probably what you want:

https://www.softwarecollections.org/en/scls/

It have all of PHP 5.5, MySQL and MariaDB 5.5. E.g. for php55 it says "Ready for production deployments.".